# ubuntu server for raspberry pi setup for POE HAT with fan

Tags: raspberrypi, fan

How to setup fan on ubuntu server for raspberry pi 4b with official POE HAT with fan? it seems the default behavior is spin and stop on an interval, or by default is temperature based behavior?

OS: ubuntu server 64-bit 20.04 LTS
devices: Pi4B + official POE HAT for Pi3&4

Thanks!

Comment: i found this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98078/poe-hat-fan-activation-on-os-other-than-raspbian that's the way to setup rule for poe hat on ubuntu server 20.04 lts for raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the POE-HAT product page says:

> The PoE HAT is fitted with a small fan that is controlled by the Raspberry Pi via I2C. The fan will turn on and off automatically depending on the temperature of the main processor on the Raspberry Pi.

You can adjust the temperature at which it triggers by editing `/boot/config.txt`.  You should find an entry like so:

```
# PoE Hat Fan Speeds
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=65000,poe_fan_temp0_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=67000,poe_fan_temp1_hyst=2000
```

Where you adjust the temps at which the fans turn on (temp0) and speed up (temp1).  The temps are in microcelsius, so 65000 is 65C.

Comment: thank you, i believe that's for raspberry pi os, for ubuntu server, it's different

Answer (score 0):

None of these options worked for me; so I ran raspi-config
-> Performance Options
-> Fan
-> GPIO 18

Comment: Did you run in on Ubuntu?

Comment: Pilot6 - I did, thank you.